# nth-child property for three column layout design?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to implement the nth-child property to the three column layout in which the posts are showing in loop.

Now I wanted to specify the nth-child property for

```
1st,4th,7th,10th,13th child respectively and so
and
2nd,5th,8th,11th,14th child respectively and so on 
and 
3rd,6th,9th,12th ,15th child respectively and so on
```

for diffrent CSS

Comment: `:nth-child(3n+1)`, `3n+2`, `3n`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this would benefit greatly from a short explanation on what :nth-child() calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child` like this. I used it all as divs in the demo.

**Html:**

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
<div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div>
<div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>
<div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div>
<div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div>
```

**Css:**

```
div {width:33%; background:grey; height:50px; float:left;}
div:nth-child(3n-1){background:green;}
div:nth-child(3n){background:blue;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2LHJ/3)**

Comment: `3n - 1`.. ? wouldn't that look for `-1` index element when `n = 0`?

Comment: @Mr_Green So? `3n+2` would look for the 1001th element when `n = 333`, but do we care?

Comment: hehe.. I was just pulling his leg :D. but seriously, will that element look for -1 index when n is 0?

Comment: I dont know... but is it valid? yes.. when using the `+` you only change de direction of the css.. in my case, turn around the colors...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all child are li, you can use `nth-child` like this.

**CSS code:**

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n+1){
   /*whatever your property may be*/
  background-color:orange;    
}

ul > li:nth-child(3n+2){

   background-color:white;    
}

ul >li:nth-child(3n){    
   background-color:green;
}
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/CUvZ8/)